# How to change to register in eureka the domain address instead of the ip

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have two services developed with **Spring Boot** deployed on **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**, when I access the url to view the services that are registered on my server using **Eureka Service Discovery**, my service is registered but it does not register with the domain and is registering with the IP address which does not help in service discovery.

Below is the status and url of the discovery of the service, which I believe is of no use to me because that way I can't hit the service to make requests.

```
ENTITY-MANAGEMENT   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-172-31-19-191.sa-east-1.compute.internal:entity-management:5000
```

I need it to be registered with the domain of my service and not with the IP address as above, below I leave an example of how it should look, presenting the domain of my service because that way I can make requests to that address.

```
ENTITY-MANAGEMENT   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - fullytask-entity-manager.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:entity-management:5000
```

I hope that an address appears that I can make requests from other applications because that's what I'm registering my services for using Eureka Service Discovery.

For me to know which services are registered I need to go to the AWS console and I don't want that.

**Is there any setting for this to change?**

Comment: Another point is that I don't need the port on which my service is registered, since Elastic Beanstalk requires that the default ports of my applications are 5000.

Comment: spring cloud makes a guess as to what host it should register with. If you don't want it to guess there are settings (I'm on mobile) you been set. The port comes from server.port by default